# IIS7.5 - Disable overlapped recycle lost session data?

Tags: session, iis-7.5

If I have "disable overlapped recycle" set to FALSE for an ApplicationPool, will that mean, that the existing session datas will be take over by the new AppPool?

I have a Webapplication which stores a few informations in session variables. Right now I have set the "disable overlapped recycle" parameter to TRUE. That means, if the current AppPool reaches the "regualr Time interval (1740 min.)" it shut down immediately and all session informations are lost. If I then try to call the session variable again, an error occured. Correct?

If I now set "disable overlapped recycle" to FALSE, will this avoid this kind of error because the existing session informations will be pushed to the new AppPool? Or is this just an performance issue because a new AppPool is already runnig before the old one is shut down?

Thanks for reading so far! ;-)
Alex

Comment: What kind of web site technology do you use? PHP? ASP.NET? Sessions have several modes (ASP.NET has in-process/session service/SQL Server for example). In-process mode stores session variables in the process memory and if application pool recycles (does not matter overlapped or not), sessions are lost.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I'm using ASP.NET... and I'm using in-process. So everything is lost after recycles. :-(